# Export R array to .npy (Numpy)

Tags: r, arrays, numpy, export

What is the best way to export an R array to a .npy file for later use in Numpy?

Toy data:

```
v1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
v2 = v1+1
v3 = v2+1
        
# Array to export = a
a <- array(c(v1,v2,v3), dim=c(3,3,3))
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- We can use `reticulate` library and import `numpy` package as `np` , then we can save and load `.npy` files

```
library(reticulate)

np <- import("numpy")
a <- np$array(a)

np$save("my_array" , a)

np$load("my_array.npy")
```

- Output

```
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    5    8
[2,]    3    6    9
[3,]    4    7   10

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    6    9
[2,]    4    7   10
[3,]    5    8   11
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `reticulate` package to accomplish this:

```
reticulate::r_to_py(a)$dump('filename.npy')
```

then go to python and do

```
import numpy as np

np.load('filename.npy', allow_pickle = True)
```